# Javascript for each instead of multiple if

Tags: javascript, ajax

Please, give "direction where to go"

Many input rows. For each row is field `class="row_changed"`

If value in the field is higher than 0, then ajax pass entire row to php. Each row is included in `<tr> </tr>` For each `<tr>` id is set `<tr id='row'>`

At the moment I can do it only with many `if`

Need something like: if value in any of field field `class="row_changed"` is more than 0, then pass corresponding row (inside `<tr id='row'>`) to php.

[**Here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is some information. Is it suitable for the described case?

```
<tr id='row1'>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="row1[]" id="date_day1" class="row_changed1">
  </td>
    ...
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="row1[]" id="is_row_changed1" size="1">
    <script>
      $(".row_changed1").on("change", function () {
        document.getElementById('is_row_changed1').value = 1;
      });
    </script>
  </td>
<tr>

if ($("#is_row_changed1").val() > 0) {
  $.post("_autosave_array.php", $("#row1 :input").serialize(), function (data1) {
    $('#load1').html(data1);
    $('#is_row_changed1').val(0)
  });
  var str = $("#row1 :input").serialize();
  $("#load1_1").text(str);
}

if ($("#is_row_changed2").val() > 0) {
  $.post("_autosave_array.php", $("#row2 :input").serialize(), function (data2) {
    $('#load2').html(data2);
    $('#is_row_changed2').val(0)
  });
  var str = $("#row2 :input").serialize();
  $("#load2_1").text(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that all your input tags have the same name, you can select all of them by name then put your condition/logic inside

sample:

```
$("input[name='row1[]']").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()>0){
            $.post("_autosave_array.php", $("#row1 :input").serialize(), function (data1) {
            $('#load1').html(data1);
            $('#is_row_changed1').val(0)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
function doPost(changedRowId,serializeRowId,resultId,serializeResultId){
  if ($(changedRowId).val() > 0) {
    $.post("_autosave_array.php", $(serializeRowId + ":input").serialize(), function (data2) {
      $(resultId).html(data2);
      $(changedRowId).val(0)
    });
    var str = $("#row2 :input").serialize();
    $(serializeResultId).text(str);
}

var rowData = [{changedRowId: "#is_row_changed1", serializeRowId: "#row1", resultId: "#load1", serializeResultId: "#load1_1"},
               {changedRowId: "#is_row_changed2", serializeRowId: "#row2 ", resultId: "#load2". serializeResultId: "#load2_1"}
              ];

for(var i = 0; i < rowData.length; ++i){
   var data = rowData[i];
   doPost(data.changedRowId,data.serializeRowId,data.resultId,data.serializeResultId);
}
```